# How to send Image from recycler view to deatil activity using picasso in Android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-recyclerview, picasso

In my app I have got image from rest api json data, which I have shown in recyclerview. Now I would like to send the image to detail activity to show this image as Cover Image. Hence I tried with the following code to do that. But I think I am making mistake to pass the correct value of image. It would be really helpful for me if someone help me to identify the problem.

**This Problem is solved**

AdapterClass

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NewsHolder holder, int position) {
        final NewsModel currentNews = mNews.get(position);
        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext());
        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(currentNews.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc()).into( holder.newsImage );        
        holder.newsHeadline.setText(currentNews.getTitle());
        holder.newsDate.setText(currentNews.getPostDate());
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               Intent i=new Intent(context,DetailNews.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.putExtra("src",currentNews.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc());
                i.putExtra("title",currentNews.getTitle());
                i.putExtra("body",currentNews.getBody());
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Detail Activity Class

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

    //RECEIVE DATA
    Log.e("_coverImage",""+_coverImage);
    String coverImage = intent.getStringExtra ("src");
    String heading=intent.getExtras().getString("title");
    //String newsDate=intent.getExtras().getString("date");
    String description=intent.getExtras().getString("body");

    //BIND DATA
   Picasso.with(this).load(coverImage ).into(_coverImage);
    _newsHeading.setText(heading);      
    _description.setText(description);
```

Comment: Why are you passing image? Just pass the image URL to the DetailActivity instead.

Comment: @Kunu which url I need to pass. could you plaese explain

Comment: `I have got image from rest api json data`, the image you are getting from API.

Comment: -- currentNews.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc();

Comment: but I have lotos of image there, for ech type of news. I have to make it dynamic

Comment: @user7439667 where can I write this line

Comment: change ** int coverImage = intent.getIntExtra("src",0);** to 

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String image = extras.getString("src");
    //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concept is not clear somewhat. You are passing String value in your Adapter and receiving integer in DeatilActivity class.

```
final NewsModel currentNews = mNews.get(position);
Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext());
Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(currentNews.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc()).into( holder.newsImage ); //Image url 

holder.newsHeadline.setText(currentNews.getTitle());
holder.newsDate.setText(currentNews.getPostDate());
holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

         Intent i=new Intent(context,DetailNews.class);
         i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         i.putExtra("src",currentNews.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc());
         i.putExtra("title",currentNews.getTitle());
         i.putExtra("body",currentNews.getBody());
         context.startActivity(i);
     }
 });
```

**DeatilActivity.java**

```
String coverImage = intent.getExtras().getString("src");
    String heading=intent.getExtras().getString("title");
    //String newsDate=intent.getExtras().getString("date");
    String description=intent.getExtras().getString("body");

//BIND DATA
//_coverImage.setImageResource(coverImage);   // Remove this line
Picasso.with(DetailActivity.this).load(coverImage ).into(_coverImage);
```

Comment: wong argument is shwoing for this line ("src","");

Comment: my bad use getStringExtra

Comment: Now shoing getStringExtra String Intent cannot be applied

Comment: Check it again.

Comment: great, then either upvote or accept the answer. Either will be fine

Comment: Yes I accept and upvote it. Could you plaese also upvote my question, if you do not mind.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get int from your intent but it's string.

```
//RECEIVE DATA
String coverImageSrc = intent.getStringExtra("src");
```

And load it with Piccasso again:

```
 Picasso.with(this).load( coverImageSrc ).into( _coverImage );
```

Instead of _coverImage.setImageResource(coverImage);

Comment: You mean instead of coverImage.setImageResource(image) i will load again wth picasso

Comment: @ktina Yes, exactly.

Comment: I am getting error that getStrinExtra (String ) in intent cannot be applied to(String, java.lang.string)

Comment: @ktina Remove second  parameter (null), sorry for that. Answer updated.